# Slightly complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql

employees
    e_id    first   last
    1   John    Smith
    2   Bob Smith
    3   Alex    Smith
    4   John    Doe
    5   Ron Doe

```
clockpunch
e_id    time    for adjustment
1   0650    in  early
3   0710    in  late
4   0725    in  early
1   1100    lunch   ---
2   1150    in  late
2   1400    lunch   ---
4   1320    out ---
```

I need a SINGLE query that will list all employee names, along with a count of how many times that user has been early, descending order by the count of times early.  How would this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select a.first,a.last,sum(case b.adjustment when 'early' then 1 else 0 end) as ct 
from employees a, clockpunch b where a.e_id=b.e_id
    group by a.first, a.last
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work (untested)

```
select first,last,count(*) from employees e, clockpunch c 
where e.e_id = c.e_id and adjustment = 'early' 
group by first,last
order by count(*) desc
```